# Angularjs :Delete function is throwing 404 error

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, webapi

I'm new to angularjs and I'm trying to get the student id for deleting the row from database using angularjs , but iim getting the error like 'api/student/delete/1' is not found

Angularjs code:

```
$scope.DeleteStudent = function (r) {
        debugger;
        $http.delete('/api/Student/Delete', { params: { id: r.StudentID } }).then(function (responsedlt) {

            if (responsedlt != null) {
                alert("Record deleted successfully !!");
            }
            else {
                alert("Error occured");
            }
        })

            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log("error is :" + error.statusText);
            });
    }
```

Api controller:

```
    [HttpDelete]

    public HttpResponseMessage Delete(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            var _get = repos.deletebyid(id);
            if (_get != null)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, _get);
            }
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Error");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
        }
    }
```

repository code:

```
    public string deletebyid(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            var student = db.tableStudents.Where(x => x.StudentID == id).FirstOrDefault();
            db.tableStudents.Remove(student);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return "Data deleted successfully";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Edit : Edited with the working code.

Comment: You are sending the **exact string text** for `r.StudentId`. What you want is the value of `r.StudentId`: `var apiRoute = "/api/Student/Delete/" + r.StudentId;` or work with [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), ```var apiRoute = `/api/Student/Delete/${r.StudentId}`;``` Also you need to check whether you are sending the request to the correct API (domain) url.

Comment: I'm sending the request to the correct API i,e.Delete and if I use template literal getting same error api/Student/Delete/${r.StudentId} not found

Comment: When you use template literal, make sure you are using the backticks (`), but not quotes (').

Comment: -1 For not including your entire Controller class with all `[Route]` attributes and making me having resort to psychic debugging.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that your missing controller class looks like this

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class StudentController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpDelete]    
    public HttpResponseMessage Delete(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            var _get = repos.deletebyid(id);
            if (_get != null)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, _get);
            }
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Error");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

You may be specifying your routing either using the default router, or explicitly like this.

If you had installed Swagger, you would note that this endpoint would corispond to the following request:

`DELETE http://localhost/api/student`

Notice that you do NOT have `delete` in the route.

This is because you don't have the word "Delete" in any of your routing.

Try again with `$http.delete('/api/Student')`.

Additionally, I would recommend that you add a `[FromQuery]` to your `int id`, if you are trying to specify it as a query string parameter.

```
 [HttpDelete]
 public HttpResponseMessage Delete([FromQuery]int id)
```

However. This is not how you would get a true HATEOS REST API from the REST region of France (it is only sparkling RPC).

Instead, try.

```
 [Route("{id}")]
 [HttpDelete]
 public HttpResponseMessage Delete([FromRoute]int id)
```

And on the JS side:

```
 $http.delete(`/api/Student/${id}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, your api url is 'api/student/delete/1' is this. but if you are using localhost then localhost:{port}/{url}, this will be the complete url and if you are using 3rd party api, need to concat that api url with 'api/student/delete/1' this.